# Django - How many DB hits cause using a model method, which access another object via Foreign Key, in template?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

Especifically, calling a model method that access another object via Foreign Key, and calling this method several times in a for-loop.

Let's assume the following models as an example:

```
class Shipment(Model):

    discount = FloatField()

    def getProducts(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(shipment = self)

class Product(Model):

    shipment = ForeignKey(Shipment)
    baseCost = IntegerField()

    def getDiscount(self):
        return self.baseCost * self.shipment.discount
```

A Shipment offers a discount percentage to each Product. The Product model has a method to get how much money it's discounting, but to calculate that, it has to access its Shipment.

(Of course, we could just store the discount as a field in Product to never calculate it again, but let's ignore that for the sake of this question).

Now, let's assume we have the following view:

```
def viewShipments(request):

    context = {
        "shipments": Shipment.objects.all(),
    }

    render(request, "template.html", context)
```

We simply pass all the Shipments as context.

Finally, let's assume the following template:

```
{% for shipment in shipments %}

    {% for product in shipment.getProducts %}

        {{ product.getDiscount }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

If my understanding of how Querysets work is correct, during the first loop it hits the DB to fetch all Shipments (so, 1 hit so far). Then in the second loop it hits the DB again to get the corresponding Products, once per Shipment (so, S hits). Finally, each Product calls its method, which access its Shipment via Foreign Key to retrieve the discount, which (I assume) causes another hit, once for each Product (P times). This last part particularly bugs me, because we are retrieving again each Shipment, which we already did in the first for-loop, but this time one by one!

In total, it's (1 + S + (S*P)) database hits, which seems a little excessive.

Is this correct, or does Django optimizes things in a way that I'm not aware of? I know that querysets are lazy and have a cache, but I don't know if they apply in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize the DB access using ***prefetch_related*** and changing getProducts to use Django Related Field manager.
prefetch will preform an additional query in the background and retrive the Relevant products thous reducing the total number of DB calls to 2.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

If you had accessed shipments from the Product objects you should have used ***select_related***. Select related performs a join of the object with another object and reducing the number of DB calls but it works only on 1-1 relations/1->many (from the other side).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/

How to do it?
Consider the following code in the models file. Notice that I'm using Django RelatedManager and accessing it with self

```
class Shipment(Model):

    discount = FloatField()

    def getProducts(self):
        return self.product_set.all()

class Product(Model):
...
```

now the magic happens we want to make django fetch all the products along with the shipments.

```
def viewShipments(request):

    context = {
        "shipments": Shipment.objects.prefetch_related('product_set').all(),
    }

    render(request, "template.html", context)
```

Notice that you must use Django 1.4 and above for that.

Comment: I think that select_related() may be more appropriate here than prefetch_related(). Also you can add related_name inside shipment = ForeignKey(Shipment, related_name="products") and then use self.products.all().

Comment: I made a quick text with 3 shipments with 3 products each. I got 13 queries normally, as I suspected. Getting the products with the Related Manager plus using Prefetch, it indeed came down to 2 queries. However, just by using the Related Manager, no Prefetch, it came down from 13 to 6 queries. I had no idea that the Related Manager was faster than just using a QuerySet, and I can't find anything in the docs, so what gives?